# What is the difference between unapply and unapplySeq?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, unapply

Why does Scala have both `unapply` and `unapplySeq`? What is the difference between the two? When should I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Without going into details and simplifying a bit:

For regular parameters `apply` constructs and `unapply` de-structures:

```
object S {
  def apply(a: A):S = ... // makes a S from an A
  def unapply(s: S): Option[A] = ... // retrieve the A from the S
}
val s = S(a)
s match { case S(a) => a }
```

For repeated parameters, `apply` constructs and `unapplySeq` de-structures:

```
object M {
  def apply(a: A*): M = ......... // makes a M from an As.
  def unapplySeq(m: M): Option[Seq[A]] = ... // retrieve the As from the M
}
val m = M(a1, a2, a3)
m match { case M(a1, a2, a3) => ... } 
m match { case M(a, as @ _*) => ... }
```

Note that in that second case, repeated parameters are treated like a `Seq` and the similarity between `A*` and `_*`.

So if you want to de-structure something that naturally contains various single values, use `unapply`. If you want to de-structure something that contains a `Seq`, use `unapplySeq`.

Answer (score 18):

Fixed-arity vs. variable arity.  [Pattern Matching in Scala (pdf)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170208120357/wiki.ifs.hsr.ch/SemProgAnTr/files/PatternMatchingInScala.pdf) explains it well, with mirroring examples.  I also have mirroring examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8282335/847099).

Briefly:

```
object Sorted {
  def unapply(xs: Seq[Int]) =
    if (xs == xs.sortWith(_ < _)) Some(xs) else None
}

object SortedSeq {
  def unapplySeq(xs: Seq[Int]) =
    if (xs == xs.sortWith(_ < _)) Some(xs) else None
}

scala> List(1,2,3,4) match { case Sorted(xs) => xs }
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
scala> List(1,2,3,4) match { case SortedSeq(a, b, c, d) => List(a, b, c, d) }
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
scala> List(1) match { case SortedSeq(a) => a }
res2: Int = 1
```

So, which do you think is exhibited in the following example?

```
scala> List(1) match { case List(x) => x }
res3: Int = 1
```

Comment: Ah thanks! That makes sense. Coming from a Haskell perspective, I think of matching on `List(a,b,c)` as desugaring into a match on `a :: b :: c :: Nil`, but it appears Scala doesn't do this; instead, it uses `List`'s `unapplySeq` method.

Comment: The paper referred in this answer can be found here: http://www.michaelrueegg.name/static/papers/PatternMatchingInScala.pdf

Comment: @dan Scala can match on Lists they way you expect, by having an unapply method on the :: companion object. As expected this unapply just destructures the List (or rather a ::) into head and tail. Note this works only for Lists, not for any Seq.

Comment: Above URLs of paper seem broken. Seems it can now be found at [http://wiki.ifs.hsr.ch/SemProgAnTr/files/PatternMatchingInScala.pdf](http://wiki.ifs.hsr.ch/SemProgAnTr/files/PatternMatchingInScala.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

```
scala> val fruit = List("apples", "oranges", "pears")
fruit: List[String] = List(apples, oranges, pears)

scala> val List(a, b, c) = fruit
a: String = apples
b: String = oranges
c: String = pears

scala> val List(a, b, _*) = fruit
a: String = apples
b: String = oranges

scala> val List(a, _*) = fruit
a: String = apples

scala> val List(a,rest @ _*) = fruit
a: String = apples
rest: Seq[String] = List(oranges, pears)

scala> val a::b::c::Nil = fruit
a: String = apples
b: String = oranges
c: String = pears

scala> val a::b::rest = fruit
a: String = apples
b: String = oranges
rest: List[String] = List(pears)

scala> val a::rest = fruit
a: String = apples
rest: List[String] = List(oranges, pears)
```