# Wrong number of arguments for pattern

Tags: scala

There is a class with a very long list of the parameters for the constructor:

```
case class ClassA(a: Int, b: String, c: Int /*and so on*/)
```

I need to do a pattern matching against it:

```
val cls = getClassA
cls match {
  case ClassA(a, _, _, _, _, /* and so on */) => Some(a)
  case ClassA(_, _, c, _, _, /* and so on */) => Some(c)
  case _ => None
}
```

And I need to capture the value of `a` or `c`. Is it possible not to specify all the other parameters by `_` if I really don't need them?

```
val cls = getClassA
    cls match {
      case ClassA(a, _*) => Some(a)
      case ClassA(_, _, c, _*) => Some(c)
      case _ => None
    }
```

It gave me the error: `wrong number of arguments for pattern ClassA(a, b, /*and so on*/)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case classes, you need to specify the entire list of parameters when matching.

An alternative would be to implement your own `unapply` method that correctly deals with whatever arguments you pass it.

Comment: In this case, `unapplySeq` might be more useful than `unapply`. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282277/what-is-the-difference-between-unapply-and-unapplyseq).

Comment: I have only a case class. In order to be ably to define unapplySeq, do I have to create a companion object ClassA and define it there?

Answer (score 4):

Since companion objects of case classes have `unapply` method, not `unapplySeq`, it doesn't work.

If you want to use `unapply` to check against only one field, you can define something like this:

```
object ClassAByA {
  def unapply(obj: ClassA) = Some(obj.a)
}

val ClassAByA(x) = ClassA(100, "thousand", 10000.0)
// x is equal 100 now

ClassA(100, "a", 10000.0) match {
  case ClassAByB(str) => str // str is equal "a" now
}
```

or you can just write:

```
something match {
  case c: ClassA => c.b
}
```